# Bronze badge proposal: Abandoned

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request

**Abandoned**

A bronze badge awarded to people who:

- ask a question,
- get a series of comments (asking for details or perhaps even comments that answer the question/hints towards the answer)
- question score >=0
- the question's activity drops to 0 within 24 hours
- no one except OP visits it in the next month
- has 0 answers

This tells us the question got activity, people were interested to help but something happened that caused OP to be abandoned (e.g OP didn't cooperate)

Comment: _"e.g OP didn't cooperate"_ We don't award badges for misbehavior.

Comment: @user0042 I mean there are a few badges that can be awarded by abusing the system, but I agree I think this one goes a bit too far. (Not by abusing the system, just awarding what we *don't* want on the site)

Comment: When I read the title I thought the status of this request was "Abandoned", like one of those questions where the OP comes back after a week and adds "Solved" at the end of the title.

Comment: @NisargShah well - could very well be, considering the feedback (which makes sense)

Comment: I think what you are trying to award here is a *really* good question that is being asked but that nobody is able to solve so they give up on it? I’ve actually seen many of those because the question was super specialized in a way that it was super interesting but at the same time not helpful at all for others (since nobody will ever get that problem). – That being said, I don’t think that’s generally a good thing. People should try to ask their questions in a way that it is interesting *and* solvable.

Comment: the behaviour you're describing is super-annoying. but badges are rewards not punishments. I think there's a tumbleweed badge for questions without comments at all BTW. Not exactly the same.

Comment: People will do this to just get the badge. Bad idea.

Comment: @Ivan you can't control this

Comment: @Adelin control what? No need to encourage such behavior. If I want to get this badge, I will create and abandon question on purpose. Many people will do this. Maybe there will be activity, maybe not. But author will have to abandon the question on purpose.

Comment: "Super specialized" questions that don't get much response are already covered by the [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge, @poke.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, we'll not add such a badge.

Badges are there to teach and to encourage desired behaviour. Having people ask questions that no one wants to interact with anymore is *not* desired behaviour, and not something we would want to teach.

Such a badge would also be the antithesis to the [Curious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious), [Inquisitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4128/inquisitive) and [Socratic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) badges, which encourage *well-received* questions, while your badge would encourage questions that are anything but.

Comment: Fair enough. But what you say contradicts with [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed)

Comment: @Adelin: Tumbleweed is there to give courage when asking questions in a unpopular topic with few experts available. *Don't worry, hopefully someone will find you an answer*.

Comment: @Adelin: note that it rewards *zero score*, not zero or lower.

Comment: @Adelin: last but not least, Tumbleweed is far more important outside of Stack Overflow, as the amount of attention per post here is easily higher than on other sites.